# TCPClient boost::asio::io_service post not firing

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I'm having an issue with boost::asio::io_service.post() not calling my method handler.
I have a simple client and server c++ app both using the same code in the TCPClient class. The client side works fine, but the instance of the class populated using accept doesn't work.

I have put my whole project up [here](http://dmcgruer.our-files.com/homemedia/) but I've put the relevant bits of code below.

In the TCPClient::Write method this line

```
io_service.post(boost::bind(&TCPClient::DoWrite, this, msg));
```

gets called but the handler (TCPCLient::DoWrite) doesn't get called on the server side.

I know the IO_Service is running because my async_reads in the same TCPClient work fine.

This is my TCPClient class

.hpp file

```
class TCPClient
  : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<TCPClient>
{
    public:
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<TCPClient> pointer;

    private:
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        bool m_IsConnected;
        bool m_HeartbeatEnabled;

        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_Socket;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint m_Endpoint;

        boost::asio::steady_timer m_HeartBeatTimer;
        boost::asio::streambuf m_Buffer;
        std::string m_Delimiter;
        std::deque<std::string> m_Messages;
        bool m_HeartBeatEnabled;
        int m_HeartBeatTime;

    private:
        void HandleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& error);
        void DoHeartBeat(const boost::system::error_code& error);
        void DoWrite(const std::string &msg);
        void HandleWrite(const boost::system::error_code& error);
        void HandleRead(const boost::system::error_code& error);

    public:
        TCPClient(boost::asio::io_service &io_service);
        TCPClient(bool enableHeartbeat);
        ~TCPClient();
        void Close();
        void ConnectToServer(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& endpoint);
        void ConnectToServer(const std::string &ip, const std::string &protocol);
        void ConnectToServer(const std::string &ip, unsigned short port);
        void Write(const std::string &msg);
        void StartRead();
        void SetHeartBeatTime(int time);  
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& Socket();
        boost::asio::io_service& Service();
        static pointer Create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service);

    public:
        // signals
        boost::signals2::signal<void(const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint&)>    sConnected;
        boost::signals2::signal<void(const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint&)>    sDisconnected;      
        boost::signals2::signal<void(const std::string&)>                       sMessage;
};
```

.cpp file

```
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

TCPClient::pointer TCPClient::Create(boost::asio::io_service& io)
{
    return pointer(new TCPClient(io));
}

TCPClient::TCPClient(boost::asio::io_service& io)
    : m_IsConnected(true), m_Socket(io), m_HeartBeatTimer(io), m_Delimiter(), m_HeartBeatTime(10)
{
    m_Delimiter = "\n"; 
    m_HeartbeatEnabled = false;
    // start heartbeat timer (optional)
    if(m_HeartBeatEnabled)
    {
        m_HeartBeatTimer.expires_from_now(boost::chrono::seconds(m_HeartBeatTime));
        m_HeartBeatTimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&TCPClient::DoHeartBeat, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
}

TCPClient::TCPClient(bool enableHeartBeat)
    : m_IsConnected(false), m_Socket(io_service), m_HeartBeatTimer(io_service), m_Delimiter(), m_HeartBeatTime(10)
{
    m_Delimiter = "\n"; 
    m_HeartbeatEnabled = enableHeartBeat;
}

TCPClient::TCPClient::~TCPClient()
{
}

void TCPClient::Close()
{
    io_service.stop();
    m_Socket.close();
}

boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& TCPClient::Socket()
{
    return m_Socket;
}

boost::asio::io_service& TCPClient::Service()
{
    return io_service;
}

void TCPClient::ConnectToServer(const std::string &ip, unsigned short port)
{
    try {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(ip), port);
        ConnectToServer(endpoint);
    }
    catch(const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

void TCPClient::ConnectToServer(const std::string &url, const std::string &protocol)
{
    //  You can also explicitly pass a port, like "8080"
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query( url, protocol );
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver( io_service );
    try {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator destination = resolver.resolve(query);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint;
        while ( destination != boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator() ) 
            endpoint = *destination++;

        ConnectToServer(endpoint);
    }
    catch(const std::exception &e) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

void TCPClient::ConnectToServer(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint& endpoint)
{
    m_Endpoint = endpoint;

    std::cout << "Trying to connect to port " << endpoint << std::endl;

    // try to connect, then call handle_connect
    m_Socket.async_connect(m_Endpoint,
        boost::bind(&TCPClient::HandleConnect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    //start processing messages
    io_service.run();
}

void TCPClient::Write(const std::string &msg)
{
    if(!m_IsConnected) return;
    std::cout << "write: " << msg << std::endl;
    // safe way to request the client to write a message
    io_service.post(boost::bind(&TCPClient::DoWrite, this, msg));
}

void TCPClient::StartRead()
{
    if(!m_IsConnected) return;

    // wait for a message to arrive, then call handle_read
    boost::asio::async_read_until(m_Socket, m_Buffer, m_Delimiter,
          boost::bind(&TCPClient::HandleRead, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}


void TCPClient::HandleRead(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        std::string msg;
        std::istream is(&m_Buffer);
        std::getline(is, msg); 

        if(msg.empty()) return;

        //cout << "Server message:" << msg << std::endl;

        // TODO: you could do some message processing here, like breaking it up
        //       into smaller parts, rejecting unknown messages or handling the message protocol

        // create signal to notify listeners
        sMessage(msg);

        // restart heartbeat timer (optional)
        if(m_HeartBeatEnabled)
        {
            m_HeartBeatTimer.expires_from_now(boost::chrono::seconds(m_HeartBeatTime));
            m_HeartBeatTimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&TCPClient::DoHeartBeat, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }

        // wait for the next message
        StartRead();
    }
    else
    {
        // try to reconnect if external host disconnects
        if(error.value() != 0) {
            m_IsConnected = false;

            // let listeners know
            sDisconnected(m_Endpoint);

            // cancel timers
            m_HeartBeatTimer.cancel();
        }
        //else
            //do_close();
    }
}

void TCPClient::HandleWrite(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if(!error)
    {
        // write next message
        m_Messages.pop_front();
        if (!m_Messages.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "Client message:" << m_Messages.front() << std::endl;

            boost::asio::async_write(m_Socket,
                boost::asio::buffer(m_Messages.front()),
                boost::bind(&TCPClient::HandleWrite, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        if(m_HeartBeatEnabled)
        {
            // restart heartbeat timer (optional)
            m_HeartBeatTimer.expires_from_now(boost::chrono::seconds(m_HeartBeatTime));
            m_HeartBeatTimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&TCPClient::DoHeartBeat, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "HandleWrite Error: " << error << std::endl;
    }
}

void TCPClient::DoWrite(const std::string &msg)
{
    if(!m_IsConnected) return;

    bool write_in_progress = !m_Messages.empty();
    m_Messages.push_back(msg + m_Delimiter);

    if (!write_in_progress)
    {
        std::cout << "Client message2: " << m_Messages.front() << std::endl;

        boost::asio::async_write(m_Socket,
            boost::asio::buffer(m_Messages.front()),
            boost::bind(&TCPClient::HandleWrite, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "DoWrite write_in_progress: " << msg << std::endl;
    }
}

void TCPClient::HandleConnect(const boost::system::error_code& error) 
{   
    if (!error) {
        // we are connected!
        m_IsConnected = true;

        // let listeners know
        sConnected(m_Endpoint);

        // start heartbeat timer (optional)
        if(m_HeartBeatEnabled)
        {
            m_HeartBeatTimer.expires_from_now(boost::chrono::seconds(m_HeartBeatTime));
            m_HeartBeatTimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&TCPClient::DoHeartBeat, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }

        // await the first message
        StartRead();
    }
    else {
        // there was an error :(
        m_IsConnected = false;

        std::cout << "Server error:" << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
}

void TCPClient::DoHeartBeat(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    // here you can regularly send a message to the server to keep the connection alive,
    // I usualy send a PING and then the server replies with a PONG
    if(!error) Write( "PING" );
}

void TCPClient::SetHeartBeatTime(int time)
{
    m_HeartBeatTime = time;
    m_HeartBeatEnabled = true;
    m_HeartBeatTimer.expires_from_now(boost::chrono::seconds(m_HeartBeatTime));
    m_HeartBeatTimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&TCPClient::DoHeartBeat, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

I accept the connections using my TCPServer

.hpp file

```
class TCPServer
{
    private:
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;

    public:
        TCPServer(int port);
        ~TCPServer();
        void Close();
        void StartAccept();

    private:
        void HandleAccept(TCPClient::pointer new_connection, const boost::system::error_code& error);

    public:
        boost::signals2::signal<void(const TCPClient::pointer&)> sig_NewClient;
};
```

.cpp file

```
TCPServer::TCPServer(int port)
    : m_acceptor(io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), port))
{
}

TCPServer::TCPServer::~TCPServer()
{
}

void TCPServer::Close()
{
    m_acceptor.close();
    io_service.stop();
}

void TCPServer::StartAccept()
{
    TCPClient::pointer new_connection = TCPClient::Create(io_service);

    m_acceptor.async_accept(new_connection->Socket(),
        boost::bind(&TCPServer::HandleAccept, this, new_connection, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

    io_service.run();

    std::cout << "Run ended for server " << std::endl;
}

void TCPServer::HandleAccept(TCPClient::pointer new_connection, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        sig_NewClient(new_connection);
        StartAccept();
    }
}
```

I am very new to boost and don't do too much work with c++ (normal c#, java etc) so I assume I am missing something fundamental but I can't find the issue.

**Sudo flow** 
**Server**
Create TCPServer 
server - StartAccept() 
On new connection call StartRead on the TCPClient instance that is generated
When receive ello write olle
when receive PING write PONG

**Client**
Connect to server
send ello
Send PING every 10 seconds

**client** receives and write to the network fine
**server** received fine but the write never make it to DoWrite or HandleWrite method

Any additional information required please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is few issues, some of them which i can see:

- Since you dont have `io_service::worker` your `io_service.run()` will stop when there is no active handlers.
- Your `TCPClient::Write` is trying to `post()` a job for socket write, but it passing reference to `std::string`, so when your `TCPClient::DoWrite` will be called, your data can be already destroyed.

There is some fundamental C++ and boost::asio usage problems, so i think its worth to start with more simple realisations.

Comment: The buffer lifetime for the write-chain looks safe to me.  In `TCPClient::Write()`, the reference will be copied by value into the `boost::bind()` functor.  The `TCPClient::DoWrite()` CompletionHandler refers to the copy by reference, and copies it into the deque, initiating the `async_write()` operation using the deque element for the buffer.  The underlying memory is then released within `async_write()`'s completion handler (`TCPClient::HandleWrite()`).

Comment: With my understanding because I have an async_accept() called before io_service.run() and the handle accept calles async_accept again the io_service should always have work to do?


Looking at the doco for bind it says "The arguments that bind takes are copied and held internally by the returned function object." This would imply to me that even if my original object goes out of scope and destroyed the value used in bind would be a copy and therefore still valid?

Answer (score 0):

The `TCPServer` accept call chain is violating an `io_service` requirement resulting in undefined behavior when it invokes `io_service.run()` within a thread that is currently servicing the event loop on the same `io_service` object.  The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.run.overload1.remarks) states:

> The `run()` function must not be called from a thread that is currently calling one of `run()`, `run_one()`, `poll()` or `poll_one()` on the same `io_service` object.

In the `TCPServer` code, the requirement is violated when the `HandleAccept()` completion handler, invoked by a thread within `io_service.run()`, calls `StartAccept()`, which will then invoke `io_service.run()` on the same `io_service`:

```cpp
                .------------------------------------.
                V                                    |
void TCPServer::StartAccept()                        |
{                                                    |
  m_acceptor.async_accept(..., &HandleAccept);  --.  |
  io_service.run();                               |  |
}                                                 |  |
                .---------------------------------'  |
                V                                    |
void TCPServer::HandleAccept(...)                    | 
{                                                    | 
  if (!error)                                        | 
  {                                                  |
    StartAccept();  ---------------------------------' 
  }
}
```

To resolve this, do not invoke `io_service.run()` within a completion handler.  Instead, consider adding an entry point that initiates the accept call-chain and runs the `io_service`, but is not part of the asynchronous call-chain loop:

```cpp
void TCPServer::StartAccept()
{
  DoStartAccept();  ---------------------------------.
  io_service.run();                                  |
}                                                    |
       .---------------------------------------------'
       |        .------------------------------------.
       V        V                                    |
void TCPServer::DoStartAccept()                      |
{                                                    |
  m_acceptor.async_accept(..., &HandleAccept);  --.  |
}                                                 |  |
                .---------------------------------'  |
                V                                    |
void TCPServer::HandleAccept(...)                    | 
{                                                    | 
  if (!error)                                        | 
  {                                                  |
    DoStartAccept();  -------------------------------' 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed the code as suggested. While that certainly fixed one bug I still have the write issue.